# VB6 get filename from path

Tags: csv, path, vb6, filenames

In my VB6 code I have the statement

```
Open CommonDialog.FileName For Input As #intFileNum
```

The problem is that CommonDialog.FileName returns an entire path and VB6 Open command needs just a filename. For example if the path is C:\temp\file_name.csv then CommonDialog.FileName will return C:\temp\file_name.csv but this Open statement in VB6 will only work with file_name.csv

I could put

```
Dim Path As String
Path = CommonDialog.FileName
Open Path For Input As #intFileNem
```

I just need to know how to remove everything in Path before the last backslash"\". Is there something in the VB6 library to do this?

The Path is drawn from a common Dialog box and the code

```
CommonDialog.DialogTitle = "Browse. . ."
    CommonDialog.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv"
    CommonDialog.ShowOpen
```

So I guess if anyone knows, I should probably ask that using ShowOpen to get the path in a public sub then using the filename from the path with Open command in a later function isn't any sort of an issue on it's own, right?

For readability I have to show Ghost up here. I use intFileNum as a long

```
Dim intFileNum As Long

Open Path1 For Input As #intFileNum

Do Until EOF(intFileNum)

Line Input #intFileNum, LineEnd
```

hopefully this information can make the situation make more sense

Comment: I've always used full paths+filenames for opening files. It's not that you can't use just a file name, but if you do you MUST set the current working directory to the folder where the file exists; failure to do so will be result in fun errors to track down.

Comment: Ok, well I am getting error 52 bad file name or number which MSDN says                                                                                                                                    "The name must start with either a letter or number. It can contain any uppercase or lowercase characters (file names aren't case-sensitive) except the following characters: quotation mark ("), apostrophe ('), slash (/), backslash (\), colon (:), and vertical bar (|)."                                                    Of Course, I tried hardcoding a test filename to debug and got the same error

Comment: and how is #intFileNem defined. Are you using FreeFile?

Comment: So maybe VB6 is having a separate issue with what I did that I alluded to in the second part f the question and giving me the wrong error or just not being clear enough on MSDN. i don;'t thinkl I've done anything to close the file which is the other part of error 52. Not sure if I should post it as a separate question but it's very confusing and hard to debug

Comment: #intFileNume is just a long after defining it as a long

Comment: You must use FreeFile. Using a static # will result in errors whenever another file is using the same handle #.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Function GetFileNameFromPath(strFullPath As String) As String
    GetFileNameFromPath = Right(strFullPath, Len(strFullPath) - InStrRev(strFullPath, "\"))
End Function
```

However, your problem is caused by either you not using FreeFile or not closing the file and it is locked.

```
Public Function SomeMethod()
    On Error GoTo errSomeMethod

    Dim lngFileHandle As Long

    lngFileHandle = FreeFile
    Open CommonDialog.FileName For Input As #lngFileHandle

    'Whatever you want here

    Close #lngFileHandle

    Exit Function
errSomeMethod:
    Close #lngFileHandle
End Function
```

Comment: this worked, the issue was the Freefile not the path. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual original question:

It is right in the manual, see [FileTitle Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238802(v=vs.60).aspx).

In other words the job is already done for you... assuming you actually need it.  But that's another issue.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing built in, but it is trivial to parse the string.

Here is a handy function.

```
Function ExtractFile(ByVal PathName As String) As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim n As Integer
' Return the filename portion of a full pathname

    f$ = PathName

    Do
        n% = InStr(f$, "\")
        If n% > 0 Then f$ = Right$(f$, Len(f$) - n%)
    Loop While n% > 0

    Do
        n% = InStr(f$, "/")
        If n% > 0 Then f$ = Right$(f$, Len(f$) - n%)
    Loop While n% > 0

    ExtractFile = f$

End Function
```

Comment: Looping to find the filename? :(

Comment: Guessing because you didn't use instrrev.